# ASB MessageReceiver ReceiveAsync crashes

Tags: c#, console, .net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

## Environment

1. Windows 10 Professional
2. .NET Core Console Application

## Code

I have an abstracted message receiver that looks like this. In this code the `entity` is the name of the `Subscription` (e.g. `user`).

```
public class AzureMessageReceiver : ITdlMessageReceiver
{
    private readonly ServiceBusConnection serviceBusConnection;
    private readonly ILogger<AzureMessageReceiver> logger;

    public AzureMessageReceiver(ServiceBusConnection serviceBusConnection, ILogger<AzureMessageReceiver> logger)
    {
        this.serviceBusConnection = serviceBusConnection;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<TdlMessage<T>> ReceiveAsync<T>(string topic, string entity) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            var subscriptionPath = EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath(topic, entity);
            var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(serviceBusConnection, subscriptionPath, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
            var message = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync();

            if (message == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var messageString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TdlMessage<T>>(messageString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, "Error receiving Azure message.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The injected `ServiceBusConnection` is constructed like this. **NOTE:** this same connection initialization *works* to *write messages* to the same `Topic` and `Subscription`.

```
services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider =>
    new ServiceBusConnection(configuration[$"{DurableCommunicationKey}:AzureConnectionString"]));
```

**UPDATE:** here is the code that wraps the call to the receiver class and is the controller for receiving messages:

```
static async void Receive(ITdlMessageReceiver receiver, ILogger logger)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var message = await receiver.ReceiveAsync<TdlMessage<object>>(topic, entity);
        if (message != null)
        {
            logger.LogDebug($"Message received. Topic: {topic}. Action: {Enum.GetName(typeof(TopicActions), message.Action)}. Message: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message)}.");

        }

        Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
    }
}
```

## Problem

Every time I execute this line `var message = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync();` it just crashes the Console app. No `Exception` and nothing in `Event Viewer`.

## What I've Tried

- Using the `Secondary Connection String` from the ASB
- Providing a timeout like `messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));`
- Changing the injected `topic` from just the *name of the topic* to the entire URL of the topic (e.g. `https://{...}.servicebus.windows.net/{topicName}`)
- Changing the `ReceiveMode` to `PeekLock`
- Tacking on `ConfigureAwait(false)` to the `ReceiveAsync` call.
- Changing the timeout to `TimeSpan.Zero`. **NOTE:** this does *not* crash the app but actually throws an `Exception` that gets logged.

Comment: How is the code being called/invoked. Have you made sure you are not using blocking calls higher up the stack?

Comment: Also, I thought MessageReceiver was an abstract class?

Comment: @Nkosi good question on the blocking calls higher up. It's being called like this: `var message = await receiver.ReceiveAsync<TdlMessage<object>>(topic, entity);` -- is that the issue? Also, this is `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` and not `Microsoft.ServiceBus` because it's .NET Core.

Comment: OK version noted. Are there any async voids?

Comment: Ok that async void should be converted to an `async Task` as well as you should be using `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`. If going async you need to go async all the way.

Comment: @Nkosi, I changed it to `async Task` and added the `await Task.Delay(sleepTime);`, but it's still failing. I wonder if it has something to do with how it's called from `static void Main`? Right now I'm just calling it at the bottom of the `Program` initialization like this `Receive(receiver, logger);`.

Comment: try making all the code async, yes, but as a console application call `Receive(receiver, logger).Wait()` wrapped in a try catch to see if you can catcg the exception and hopefully reveal what is causing the fault.

Comment: @Nkosi add that collection of changes as the answer; that fixed it!

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async void` should be converted to an `async Task` as well as you should be awaiting `Task.Delay` instead of invoking `Thread.Sleep`. If going async you need to go async all the way

```
static async Task Receive(ITdlMessageReceiver receiver, ILogger logger) {
    while (true) {
        var message = await receiver.ReceiveAsync<TdlMessage<object>>(topic, entity);
        if (message != null) {
            logger.LogDebug($"Message received. Topic: {topic}. Action: {Enum.GetName(typeof(TopicActions), message.Action)}. Message: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message)}.");    
        }    
        await Task.Delay(sleepTime);
    }
}
```

Try making the code async all the way through, yes, but as a console application (single thread) you will be allowed to call `Wait()` on the `Receive` method in `Main` as it is not mixing calls that would cause problem with the async flow.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {

    //...
    //...
    //...


    Receive(receiver, logger).Wait();
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)